# cancellAllGoals() to stop a robot?

Tags: navigation, move-base, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm quite new to ActionLibs and while going trough the several tutorials regarding action servers and clients, I started to think about the client functions

- cancellAllGoals()
- cancellGoal()

I'm currently using move_base to send goals to a robot, with action libs.
Supposing I gave to a robot a goal position in a map, can I stop it using one of the two aforementioned functions?

Thank you all,
T

EDIT after dornhege reply:
This is the reply I hoped to receive. Assuming that cancellAllGoals() actually stops the robot's motion, I have the following problem..

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
MoveBaseClient ac("move_base", true);
…

ac.cancelAllGoals();

Previous code doesn't stop the robot. Am i doing something wrong?
(consider that the way I send goals works fine)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48968/cancellallgoals()-to-stop-a-robot?/) by [Tambo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3193/tambo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that's what they're intended for.

For example, I usually put this in a SIGINT handler for our executive to stop all actions, when the user interrupts with Ctrl-C.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0